# Matching brackets in Rust

Tags: algorithm, rust

I implemented the solution to the classic *Matching Brackets* problem:

*Given a string containing brackets [], braces {}, parentheses (), or any combination thereof, verify that any pairs are matched and nested correctly.*

The code should be correct since it passes several test cases.

I would like to know if:

- the usage of the `enum Bracket` is an idiomatic construct or a useless complexity
- the function `brackets_are_balanced` can be simplified while keeping the `enum Bracket`
- further improvement/suggestions

````rust
#![warn(missing_crate_level_docs)]
#![warn(missing_docs)]
//! # Matching Brackets
//!
//! `matching_brackets` is a collection of utilities to solve [this exercise](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/8ecfdc024536471a8c36ac2a3ff4b119).

enum Bracket {
    OPEN(char),
    CLOSE(char),
}

impl Bracket {
    pub fn new(c: char) -> Option<Bracket> {
        match c {
            '{' | '[' | '(' => Some(Bracket::OPEN(c)),
            '}' => Some(Bracket::CLOSE('{')),
            ']' => Some(Bracket::CLOSE('[')),
            ')' => Some(Bracket::CLOSE('(')),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

/// Check if the input `string` has balanced brackets.
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```rust
/// use matching_brackets::brackets_are_balanced;
/// assert!(brackets_are_balanced("(((185 + 223.85) * 15) - 543)/2"));
/// assert!(brackets_are_balanced("([{}({}[])])"));
/// assert!(!brackets_are_balanced("{[)][]}"))
/// ```
pub fn brackets_are_balanced(string: &str) -> bool {
    let mut brackets: Vec<Bracket> = vec![];
    for c in string.chars() {
        match Bracket::new(c) {
            Some(Bracket::OPEN(char_bracket)) => {
                brackets.push(Bracket::OPEN(char_bracket));
            }
            Some(Bracket::CLOSE(char_close_bracket)) => match brackets.pop() {
                Some(Bracket::OPEN(char_open_bracket)) => {
                    if char_close_bracket != char_open_bracket {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                _ => return false,
            },
            _ => (),
        };
    }
    brackets.is_empty()
}
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the introduction of `enum Bracket` is good and idiomatic. However, this is not the only useful form, there are at least 2 other forms that would work just fine.
- `brackets_are_balanced` can be simplified when we notice that all `Bracket`s in `Vec<Bracket>` are of the `Open` variant, so we do not need to store `Bracket`s, just their `char`s.
- the introduction of `fn new` is against standard practice. A conversion constructor should not be called `fn new` and every constructor should return only Self (= `Bracket`). That's why the function should be renamed to `from_char`.
- it's common practice to name enum variants with `PascalCase`, in your program, `Bracket::Open` and `Bracket::Close`. Not sure why you did all uppercase.
- the result of `brackets.pop()` does not need matching, it can be simply compared.

The refactored code is

````rust
#![warn(missing_crate_level_docs)]
#![warn(missing_docs)]
//! # Matching Brackets
//!
//! `matching_brackets` is a collection of utilities to solve [this exercise](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/8ecfdc024536471a8c36ac2a3ff4b119).

enum Bracket {
    Open(char),
    Close(char),
}

impl Bracket {
    pub fn from_char(c: char) -> Option<Bracket> {
        match c {
            '{' | '[' | '(' => Some(Bracket::Open(c)),
            '}' => Some(Bracket::Close('{')),
            ']' => Some(Bracket::Close('[')),
            ')' => Some(Bracket::Close('(')),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}

/// Check if the input `string` has balanced brackets.
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```rust
/// use matching_brackets::brackets_are_balanced;
/// assert!(brackets_are_balanced("(((185 + 223.85) * 15) - 543)/2"));
/// assert!(brackets_are_balanced("([{}({}[])])"));
/// assert!(!brackets_are_balanced("{[)][]}"))
/// ```
pub fn brackets_are_balanced(string: &str) -> bool {
    let mut brackets: Vec<char> = vec![];
    for c in string.chars() {
        match Bracket::from_char(c) {
            Some(Bracket::Open(char_bracket)) => {
                brackets.push(char_bracket);
            }
            Some(Bracket::Close(char_close_bracket)) => {
                if brackets.pop() != Some(char_close_bracket) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    brackets.is_empty()
}
```
````

Comment: great thanks! could you elaborate more about: "there are at least 2 other forms that would work just fine". 
Specifically, what are the "2 other forms"?

Comment: @Angelo we can rearrange this definition: `enum Bracket1 {
    Paren(Direction),
    CurlyBrace(Direction),
    SquareBracket(Direction),
}

struct Bracket2 {
    direction: Direction,
    kind: BracketKind,
}

enum BracketKind { Paren, CurlyBrace, SquareBracket }
enum Direction { Open, Close }`

Comment: thanks, clear, one last question: I saw several code snippets where `new` was used with multiple input parameters. could you give me some references/reasons why `new` should not contain any parameter?

Comment: @Angelo that's wrong, my bad. I looked into what the standard library does, and found that `new` can take arguments, but these arguments tend to be very simple like in your case. Still, I should have just said that calling the function `from_char` is more descriptive, since you're doing a conversion.